# How to verify two user who are friends on facebook

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working a mobile application based on facebook.  The application creates local user by facebook login. The steps of application are below.

1. Login With Facebook
2. Backend Service Create Local User
3. Find Friends Who use The App By Facebook SDK
4. Vote Your Friends

Notes:

1. I don't want to keep user friends on my database system
2. I use JWT

Problem:

I have to verify that authenticated user and voted user are friends on facebook. The user must be voted by its friends.

I found a couple solution but they have vulnerability too.

For instance;

I authenticated and i fetched all my friends by facebook sdk. The request is to vote a user like this:
/vote/user_id/vote_id
The backend service checks and verifys jwt token and vote user whose id is user_id as vote_id by authenticated user.

```
table structure

from_user_id,vote_id,to_user_id
```

So the problem is that when a user authenticate, it can vote a user from application outside taking jwt token whether it is its friend or not. This is a realy big problem for us. So I wonder how can verify two user are friends without send request to facebook for it. Or how can design the archtecture to avoid this situtation.

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be done making a request to

```
/me/friends/{id_of_friend}
```

using the current app user’s access token. If they are friends, you will get back a `data` structure that contains the friend’s id and name – if they aren’t friends, `data` will be an empty array.

This of course requires that both users have granted `user_friends` permission to your app.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i mean it is there a way to verify two user are friends on it  without go to facebook services.

Comment: What do you mean, without making an API request? Well as you said you don’t want to store the information on your end – so without an API request, where else would you expect it to come from …?

Comment: Yes, without making an api request. If i know the answer i did not ask it. The question is not about just verifying two user relationship, it is also about client server architecture. I tried to find a solution but i didt't. So I do not have any idea where it comes.

Comment: Well someone has to _store_ that information, if you want to be able to request it, no? And if that’s not you, that leaves only Facebook. And if both options are not satisfactory to you, then your question is rather about _magic_ …